# R: Character variable becomes numeric after cbind() and data.frame()

Tags: r, character, numeric

I try to combine one column with a data.frame. I used both cbind() and data.frame(), but after that the character variable became a numeric one.

```
>is.character(new_listing_zip)
[1] TRUE
> new_race_disp_use2 <- cbind(new_listing_zip,opo_trans) 
> is.character(new_race_disp_use2$new_listing_zip)
[1] FALSE

> is.character(new_listing_zip)
[1] TRUE
> new_race_disp_use2 <- data.frame(new_listing_zip,opo_trans) 
> is.character(new_race_disp_use2$new_listing_zip)
[1] FALSE
```

Does anyone could help me with this? Thank you.

Comment: Please revise your question by including a reproducible example. But, by default, it should be the opposite, i.e. numeric coerced into character, particularly with `cbind`. Also, something like `new_race_disp_use2$new_listing_zip` should return an error right after a `cbind`. So please revise.

Comment: @Pascal - if I had to guess I'd say that `opo_trans` is a data frame (which is why no error is returned) and that `new_listing_zip` is being converted to a factor rather than numeric.  OP might want to look into `stringsAsFactors` argument. Agreed more info is needed.

Comment: @Jay I agree it might be the reason.

Answer (score 1):

if you check the help files for data.frame() I think you will find your answer

```
 ?data.frame
```

You'll want to set your

```
options(stringsAsFactors = TRUE)
```

to change it globally or just set your parameter for

```
stringsAsFactors = TRUE
```

when declaring your data.frame, assuming these are actual character strings. Otherwise I would simply declare your variable as a factor when joining it

```
new_race_disp_use2 <- cbind(factor(new_listing_zip),opo_trans)
```

Now of course if your 'factor' is actually a numeric you want as a string (seemingly zip codes in your example) you'll want to either set your zip codes as strings to begin with using quotes (i.e. "12345") or set the data type after the data.frame is built

```
 new_race_disp_use$new_listing_zip <- as.character(new_race_disp$new_listing_zip)
```

or

```
as.factor(varName)
```

or simply

```
factor() instead of as.character()
```